# Set Input Value with Javascript - Wont POST on Submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms, post

I'm trying to get data from an API and post it to a database, the form I have worked when you manually input data. but when you set the data from the API request - it updates on the page. Although shows blank when it posts.

I'm using

```
document.getElementById('Title').value = item.volumeInfo.title;
```

to get the "Value" in an Input.

and

```
    <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Authors</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" id="Author" ng-model="book.Author" required="required"/>
        </div>
```

to attach to form.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="AddNewForm.$invalid ||
isUnchanged(book)" id="add-new-btn"
ng-click="New_Book(book)">Add</button>
```

Why is it submitting as blank?

Comment: What is the type of your input ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: My Input in just "text"

Comment: Please, post something that we can work with. It is impossible in the current state.

Comment: How do you submit the "form"? What do you do before submitting? Any event listeners?

Comment: Hey! I've added the submit - it's basically posting to an Angular Controller. the only js thing is the initial data posted via the javascript function to the inputs. then it just posts the form

Answer (score 1):

Your form elements submit their value via their “name” attribute... does you input element generate a name attribute? If not, this is why it won’t work.

Eg

```
<input name=“foo” value=“bar”/>
```

Submits as:

```
?foo=bar
```

Comment: Really not sure what you mean, sorry! can you explain it differently?

Comment: If you are trying to submit your form via HTTP or serializing the content you will need a `name` attribute as that is what the browser uses for each key/value pair. The browser does NOT use the `id` attribute.

Comment: Ahh I see! Although the form does post to the database If i manually type in the data (Its angular to pass data from the database) not sure how you would use the name attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear enough for me. But I've tried to make a quick example and make it as general as possible to let you work with your form inputs!

Here is a [Live Preview](https://jsfiddle.net/Elharony/uLp174ue/9/)

### HTML

```
<form action="post" id="myForm">
   <input type="text" id="title">
   <input type="submit" value="Click To Update">
</form>

<h2 id="result"></h2>
```

### JavaScript

```
// Select our main elements (form, text input, result heading)
const form = document.getElementById("myForm");
const titleInput = document.getElementById("title");
const result = document.getElementById("result");

form.onsubmit = function(e) {

  // Don't refresh the page
  e.preventDefault();

  // Set the input value into the result heading
  result.innerHTML = titleInput.value;
}
```

This solution allows you to write anything in your `input`, and after `submitting` your form. You can use that data elsewhere.

Comment: I think I may have phrased the question badly, 

I enter a book name in a search button, it uses the google books api to populate the form with the js value function. 

so the data is there in the page, but when I submit it, its blank. Although if I manually type into the form, it posts fine.

Comment: Good. Are you using an `Event Listener` when you are passing the data? For example; I used `onsubmit` event to pass the `titleInput` value to the `result` heading.

Comment: I have "ng-click="New_Book(book)" on my form that posts it into Angular, if thats what you mean?